# C++ - RTSP Client with Qt GUI using live555 lib what else do i need?

Tags: c++, qt, video-streaming, rtsp, live555

i like to be able to  watch video streaming with my application im doing in Qt 
first i checked vlc , but its GPL , and also i don't need all its option then i saw it is using live555 that is LGPL for streaming , my Question can i use this library in mt Qt application ? and how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what platform are you running on?

You can use Live555 *only* for RTSP/RTP purposes. Live555 however does not contain any decoders, etc.

VLC uses Live555 internally for RTSP AFAIK, but also contains a bunch of other plug-ins, decoders, demultiplexers, etc.

You still need a media framework to handle the media format specific decoding, demultiplexing, rendering etc. On Windows this can be accomplished using DirectShow. In this scenario you can wrap the live555 in a DirectShow source filter and construct a media pipeline. To get the video to display in your Qt application, you would need to investigate how you would parent the DirectShow video renderer window onto your Qt application.

Another cross-platform media framework I am not familiar with is [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/features/).

Edit:

Have you looked at Qt [Phonon](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/phonon-overview.html) at all? It looks like they've begun integrating multimedia into the framework, though you'll have to investigate if they support RTSP, and if not, how to get the media data received via Live555 into the Qt media pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Live555 libraries which is LGPL in your application. Frontend can be implemented using QT, MFC or Java.  Live555 provides APIs for establishing RTSP sessions, and for audio/video implementation probably you may need to override few functions. Go through sample applications provided by live555 in its testProgs folder.

If you are making commercial application dont forget to include Live555 license in your releases.

Comment: does the lib give me video options , i mean presentation layer ?

Comment: Library will provide you video/audio buffer. Display part you have to manage.

Comment: - You can't use Live555 with Java for a frontend. Live555 is a c++ library. Also, it's not a matter of overriding a few functions: live555 provides NO decoding capabilties and handles only the transport layer.